# XmlAdapter to JAXB-bind Joda Time Interval?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jodatime

I've been stuck for a few hours with a problem in my JAXB bindings for a web service:

In order to prepare for a bigger web service that has to return Joda Time class instances (Instant, Duration, Interval, etc.) I've started with a web service that has only one method returning an Interval:

```
package jodaws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.joda.time.Interval;

@WebService(name = "JodaWS")
public class JodaWebService {

    public Interval readInterval() {
        return new Interval(30, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:10100/JodaWS", new JodaWebService());
    }
}
```

Publishing this web service I receive an exception stating "org.joda.time.Interval does not have a no-arg default constructor":

```
29.05.2011 17:24:07 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class jodaws.jaxws.ReadInterval
29.05.2011 17:24:07 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:456)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:475)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:102)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
    at jodaws.JodaWebService.main(JodaWebService.java:17)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.joda.time.Interval does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.joda.time.Interval
        at public org.joda.time.Interval jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse._return
        at jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse
org.joda.time.base.BaseInterval does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.joda.time.base.BaseInterval
        at org.joda.time.Interval
        at public org.joda.time.Interval jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse._return
        at jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:140)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.joda.time.Interval does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.joda.time.Interval
        at public org.joda.time.Interval jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse._return
        at jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse
org.joda.time.base.BaseInterval does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.joda.time.base.BaseInterval
        at org.joda.time.Interval
        at public org.joda.time.Interval jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse._return
        at jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:148)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:140)
    ... 13 more
```

So I've read several tutorials etc. and ended up writing my own XmlAdapter for the Interval class - the first implementation returns valid but constant values:

```
package jodaws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import org.joda.time.Interval;

public class IntervalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Interval> {
    @Override
    public Interval unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return new Interval(10, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Interval v) throws Exception {
        return "10-20";
    }
}
```

And additionally I've annotated my web method to use the adapter:

```
package jodaws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
// import added
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.joda.time.Interval;

@WebService(name = "JodaWS")
public class JodaWebService {

    // annotation added
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntervalAdapter.class)
    public Interval readInterval() {
        return new Interval(30, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:10100/JodaWS", new JodaWebService());
    }
}
```

Now it should work. But when I start the web service again, I still receive an exception, though a different one:

```
29.05.2011 17:27:33 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class jodaws.jaxws.ReadInterval
29.05.2011 17:27:34 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class jodaws.jaxws.ReadIntervalResponse
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value class jodaws.IntervalAdapter
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createResponseWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getResponseWrapperClass(RuntimeModeler.java:293)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:688)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:612)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:401)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:456)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:475)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:102)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
    at jodaws.JodaWebService.main(JodaWebService.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value class jodaws.IntervalAdapter
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.newConstItem(ClassWriter.java:893)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationWriter.visit(AnnotationWriter.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createBeanImage(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createResponseWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:265)
    ... 14 more
```

And that's where I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that you will need to use an [`XmlAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for this use case.  Below is an example of how it could be done:

**IntervalStringAdapter**

The adapter below will convert instances of Interval to/from Strings in the format start-end.

```
package blog.joda;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import org.joda.time.Interval;

public class IntervalStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Interval>{

    @Override
    public Interval unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        int dashIndex = v.indexOf('-');
        long start = Long.valueOf(v.substring(0, dashIndex));
        long end = Long.valueOf(v.substring(dashIndex + 1));
        return new Interval(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Interval v) throws Exception {
        return v.getStartMillis() + "-" + v.getEndMillis();
    }

}
```

**Root**

Below is an example of how to configure the property to use the adapter:

```
package blog.joda;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.joda.time.Interval;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Interval interval;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntervalStringAdapter.class)
    public Interval getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(Interval interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package blog.joda;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/blog/joda/input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <interval>10-20</interval>
</root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html