# JAXB truncates long values

Tags: java, jaxb, truncate

I am using JAXB to convert a bean to JSON. When the JAXB converts the bean values ​​of type *long* are truncated.

Example:

If my long has the value: 44444444444444444
JAXB truncates it like this: 44444444444444450

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The JAXB (JSR-222) specification does not cover converting objects to/from JSON.  The problem you are hitting comes from an JSON-binding implementation that leverages the JAXB metadata.  Below I will demonstrate that this use case works perfectly when MOXy is used as the JSON-binding provider.

**Java Model (Foo)**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private long bar;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum16821525/input.json");
        Foo foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
{
   "bar" : 44444444444444444
}
```

Comment: Ok then, I could not see the link with the configuration, has a proxy at work preventing me from accessing.

I would like to create an interceptor to convert long value to a String?
I think so the problem would also be solved, am I right?

Comment: @user2433783 - You shouldn't need to do that.  What environment are you running in?  What are you using as your JSON-binding provider?

Comment: I'm using the default libs server Jboss 7.1, one of the requirements of the project is not using any lib other than the defaults.

Comment: @user2433783 - I understand that.  But I suspect your JSON-binding provider isn't JAXB based (since JAXB impls don't have this bug)) so a JAXB based solution probably won't work for you.

Comment: Man that sucks, I was reading the documentation RESTEasy, they said the implementation of the JAX-B is used to default.

I tried to use the interceptor and not working for JSON, only XML

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm still at work and do not have access to the link you mentioned configuration, I'm willing to try to see if it resolves.

Note: Looking deeper I saw that the provider is the JSON RESTEasy
http://jettison.codehaus.org/

Comment: @user2433783 - Jettison is used sometimes in conjunction with a JAXB impl to produce JSON (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html).  Maybe there is a bug in the JAXB impl used by RESTEasy and an `XmlAdapter` could be used to solve your use case.

Comment: `XmlAdapter` example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168663/xmladapter-to-jaxb-bind-joda-time-interval/6177534#6177534

Comment: Dude I tried to create an adapter before you even post this question, but I realized that it is only invoked when I convert a bean to XML, JSON MediaType when using it just is not called.

Comment: @user2433783 - Ok that confirms that a JAXB impl isn't being used for your use case.